# touchesCancelled triggered when using three fingers

Tags: ios, iphone, touch-event, touchescancelled

I have a simple app that prints the coordinates of all the touches event.
In the simulator it works great.

On my device (iPhone) it works great *with up to two fingers*. When I tap with three fingers in a fast sequence the event `touchesCancelled` is triggered.

Could someone please explain this to me?
This is the code for printing (in case the problem lays there) that sits in my UIView.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        NSLog(@"Began  %f %f",  location.x, location.y);
    }
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{  
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        NSLog(@"Moved  %f %f",  location.x, location.y);
    }
}


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        NSLog(@"Ended  %f %f",  location.x, location.y);
    }
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Phase: Touches cancelled");

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        NSLog(@"Cancelled  %f %f",  location.x, location.y);

    }
}
```

An example of sequence is this one:

```
Began  38.000000 263.000000
Began  173.500000 238.500000
Moved  41.500000 263.000000
Phase: Touches cancelled   <<<< third touch
Cancelled  41.500000 263.000000
Cancelled  173.500000 238.500000
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify. If you use three fingers without a 'fast sequence' does it still cancel or does it work correctly?

Comment: Sometimes touchesCancelled: is not called and that is usually when I use the three fingers "slowly".

Comment: It seems weird that there's a problem with just three touches...

Comment: Is there maybe a gesture recognizer listening and triggering touchesCancelled? I have implemented none... but maybe the iPhone does something automatically.